# How can you test the parceling of a view with Espresso?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I need to test that my custom view's state is properly saved on activity recreation.

How can I test for this? Can this be tested with Espresso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [activity.recreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) and the activity will be recreated with its `savedInstanceState`

```
@Test
public void testStateParceling() throws Exception {
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainToolbar.updateToolbarWithSelection(MainContentView.DEVICE_ACTIVITY);
            activity.recreate();
        }
    });

    checker.checkToolbarTitle(MainContentView.DEVICE_ACTIVITY);
}
```